# Solution of a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following initial value problem

$$\begin{align}
& \frac{dy}{dx} -\frac{1}{x}y=1-\frac{1}{e^x} \\  
& \text{ with } y(1)=0
\end{align}$$

I solved and  I  got this,

$$\frac{y}{x} = x\ln|x|+cx -\int\frac{e^x}{x}dx $$

but couldn't solve $\displaystyle \int\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx $ because I think it is divergent.
Please help me solve this.

Comment: It looks like you have some algebra errors in your result. However, you do end up with the Exponential Integral, but it should be for $e^{-x}$ (algebra issue I believe).

Comment: How about you write $y' -1/x y = 1 - e^{-x}$ and rework this? You should be getting $y(x) = x(\ln x + c - \displaystyle \int e^{-x})$. We have the exponential integral, which is fine to leave like that.